# how to stop armature from deforming certain parts of mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

I'm making a robot character where the model is just some blocks connected to what are supposed to be spring-like joints as the arms, and so I want to make it so that the block parts don't deform but are still affected by the armatures. how do I do this?

Comment: for objects like machines, robots, etc, instead of parenting With Automatic Weight, parent With Empty Groups, then switch your object to Edit mode, select each part and assign it to the group it is supposed to be part of (with the name of the bone that is supposed to control). Is it what you want?

Comment: yes, thank you!